# Ocultar posts de SimpleJob plugin en busqueda general

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, wordpress-plugin

Tengo el widget busqueda en mi sección de blog, al buscar me muestra también información del plugin Simple Job Board pero esta información no quiero que se mestre.
¿Como puedo lograr que esa información no se muestre?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Search only posts on blog page
function my_home_category( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_home_category' );
```

Solo era cuestión de modificar la busqueda principal